# Size limitations of the Parse Local Datastore

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is there a limit to how many objects can be pinned to the local datastore? Or is the based on the size of the device's hard disk?

Assuming the parse local datastore has let say max 30Mb of text data stored. Is there much of a performance hit to search all of this? i.e. Is Parse designed for these sort of quantities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything regarding local store max space.

The only thing that you should keep in mind about is that the query limit (1000) still applies when it comes to local data store.

About performance, we have several scenarios:

- fast device / fast network
- fast device / slow network
- slow device / fast network
- slow device / slow network

So depending on your scenario and the amount of data you would want (or not) to pin   the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can we say that disk access should be faster than network access as a general rule of thumb?  If so it would imply that local data store should (generally) improve performance of all queries (all other things being equal).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question does it? But to answer yours, which hopefully wasn't rhetorical, objects retrieved from a network are most likely stored somewhere too. So to be faster, the transit time *and* database retrieval time combined should be faster than the time to retrieve from a local database. As remote databases are mostly optimized in hardware and software, we could assume it to be true in most cases but I'd hardly call it a rule of thumb. Especially considering network congestion and buffer overflows.

Comment: Fair comment though I did suggest that "all other things being equal" which would rule out network congestion buffer overflows etc. in a more general scenario.

Comment: One followup on this I've since discovered.  Upon inspecting the local datastore itself (at least on IOS) it looks like the local datastore is simply composed of JSON strings in a structured database.  As a result all of the performance ideas I had on this really don't apply as full text searches on fields containing JSON data as strings (and then subsequent joins across other full text searches also containing JSON strings for pointers etc.) really don't seem that efficient (or quick).